# getting field name as a string in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I have this from the matlab reference manual

`value = getfield(struct, 'field')`

where struct is a 1-by-1 structure, returns the contents of the specified field, equivalent to

`value = struct.field`

how can I do the opposite

getStringName(struct.field) which return `'field'`

also if it is possible to point at the field in numerical way similar to an array

like struct{1} for field 1 `field`

**edit**

if I do the follow

structName(1) 
I get a list of field names, and dimentions

```
                Speed: [2244x1 double]
                 Time: [2244x1 double] ... and so on
```

I want to grab the title speed as string, and if possible

structName(1).filed(1) for Speed without doing  structName(1).Speed

I want to print each field into a file with the field name!

so if I do

```
for i=1:sizeOfStruct
   printToFile(structName(i)); %<=== accessing field by index, problem 2
end

function printToFile(structField)
   structFieldStr = getStrFiledName(structField); %<=== obtain field string, main problem
   filename = strcat(fileLoc, '/profile/', structFieldStr, '.dat');
   %...   then open file and dump everything
end
```

Comment: Unless it appears left of an assignment, `struct.field` is just a value, for example `2.5`, and no longer has any ties to the struct object.

Comment: Does the [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) function give what you want, or are you trying to find the field which contains a certain value?  You can also try [`inputname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html), not sure if that works with structure members

Comment: fieldnames gave me one part, whats left is grabbing that field by its location, or field name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the complete answer to your question, but this should get you started:

```
s.a = 11;
s.b = 22;
s.c = 33;
names = fieldnames(s);
for i = 1:length(names)
    fprintf('Field %s = %g\n', names{i}, s.(names{i}))
end
```

Result:

```
Field a = 11
Field b = 22
Field c = 33
```

Note the syntax to programmatically access a field name: `s.(name)`, where `s` is a struct and name is a string.

Comment: Reference to non-existent field 'fieldnames'. is the error I get if I tried s.fieldnames, however I used fieldnames(s), however s.(name) still not working 'Undefined function or variable 'a'.'

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing out some bugs, should work now. That is what you get when posting untested code ...